# python gdb multi core debug stop handler

Tags: python, gdb, multicore

When using python gdb extension, stop handler event couldn't be catched for the first breakpoint stop. But after the first breakpoint, other breakpoints cause to raise stop handler successfully. This case is only occured during multi-core debug. Everything is OK for single core debug. Is there any configuration to set stop handler for multi core debug case, since gdb uses 2 threads in that case.

Comment: gdb isn't multi-threaded.  Not sure if that matters.  From the behavior you've described, you've found a bug; but a bug report would need some sort of reproducer.

Comment: i mean when you write "info threads" on gdb command line, there are 2 threads which are shown for each cpu(core 0 and core1). And stop handler starts to be triggered after second thread is created / activated .In especially, after switching to thread 2 message appeared. Hence for the first breakpoint stop handler can not catch event.